# Create an SVG using data from Views

Tags: views, javascript

I am looking for a way to create a dynamically-generated SVG graphic based on data returned in a view from the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Since Views creates lists and SVG is ultimately XML and therefore DOM-based, they seem perfectly well-suited to work together.

I have seen a few posts around saying that SVG support/integration in Drupal is very limited, and I have only ever seen Javascript used to create an SVG and then manipulate it's DOM. There are some popular javascript libraries already in use, such as [Raphaël](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) and [svgweb](https://github.com/bewest/svgweb).

Has anyone seen PHP used to do this as well? I have seen the [SVG Embed](http://drupal.org/project/svg_embed) module but it's very new, hasn't been updated since July, and almost nobody is using it.

Does anyone know of a better way to integrate SVG and Drupal Views?

Comment: What type of SVG are you looking to create? I wouldn't say that SVG integration in Drupal is limited; it just depends on the use case. If you want to upload an SVG into an image field, then you're out of luck - and arguably rightly so, as (like you say) an SVG is XML, and not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact use case (I'm assuming you want to just use Views to use the results to build an SVG); it sounds like building a custom Views display style plugin might be in order.

There's a tutorial on Drupal.org (for Drupal 8, but the premise is the same), although I must confess I've only skim read it; and haven't tried implementing it: [Building a Views display style plugin for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2679022).